# how works DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I wonder how works the DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS.

- How long is kept the data for a table? I have tables with timestamp
  on Dec/2019
- What does it mean when a table is not in
  DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS? do it mean the table hasn't had (delete,
  insert, update) in a period? if yes, for how long?
- I have a Schema    with around 1000 tables, only around 300 appear in
  DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS

Answer (score 2):

DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS is used by Oracle internally to track how many inserts, updates and deletes have been done to a table or table partition since the stats had been gathered on it with dbms_stats.

What version of Oracle are you using  because  after Oracle 9 it is automatically inserted
into the DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS table, before oracle 9 you have to register a table as MONITORED.

Comment: We're using 11g. What about tables with timestamp on dec/2019, does it mean the last gather stat on that table was dec/2019. if the table is not on dba_tab_modifications means the table never gather stats?

Comment: "What about tables with timestamp on dec/2019,"  Where are you seeing this supposed 'table timestamp'?  Tables, in and of themselves, do not have timestamps.  _ACTIONS_ have timestamps.  Actions like issuing ddl, actions like gathering stats.  So it is critical to know exactly what it was you queried to see this.